# Is there a function/workaround to combining results from more than one table

Tags: sql

I am using a dataset of a fictional bike sharing service. The data altogether emcompasses 12 months of data, split into 12 tables, one for each month. The columns and datatypes are consistent, and I am focusing on two columns - member-type and ride_length. The member_type column only has two values, 'member' or 'casual'. I want to compare the average ride length between member and casual riders for each month but have the results displayed on one table.

The results should look like this:

member_type | january | february | march
member      |   100   |    50    |  30
casual      |    60   |    45    |  25

The one solution I can think of is to combine all the tables into one big table, create a month column and go from there, but I don't want to do that if I can help it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CTE to build the table you don't want to create on the fly.

```
with combined as (
   select 1 as month, T.* from jan_tbl T union all
   select 2, T.* from feb_tbl T union all
...
)
select  from combined
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your data model. You should not have one table per month. All those ride values should be in the same table with a column for month. The fact that the columns are the same in all the month tables is a clue.

Then you'd execute a query like this:

```
select month, member_type, sum( ride_length ) as ride_length
  from mytable
 group by month, member_type
```

This will give you results like:

```
month      member_type   ride_length
---------- ------------- -----------
january    member        100
january    casual        60
february   member        50
february   casual        45
march      member        30
march      casual        25
```

That gives you the data that you want, though you really want to turn the month column into additional columns. That's a *pivot* and the syntax to do that will vary with your database.